# Use PWm and zero_cross_detect interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

I use an Arduino Uno for controlling one DC motor speed with PWM and one dimmer for control heater.
The dimmer and PWM control worked standalone, but when I want them to work together, the dimmer doesn't work.

```
#include  <TimerOne.h>          /
#include <Wire.h> 


 //////////////                    //pin 2 zero kesmesi icin
int isiticiPWM = 9;                //  Opto Triac isitici PWM icin
int fanPWM=11;                     //motor pwm pini

int hiz=0;

volatile int i=0;               // Variable to use as a counter volatile as it is in an interrupt
volatile boolean zero_cross=0;  // Boolean to store a "switch" to tell us if we have crossed zero


char   data ;
int dim = 255;                    // Dimming level (0-128)  0 = on, 128 = 0ff
int inc=5;    // counting up or down, 1=up, -1=down
int freqStep = 75;    // This is the delay-per-brightness step in microseconds.


void zero_cross_detect() {    
  zero_cross = true;               // set the boolean to true to tell our dimming function that a zero cross has occured
  i=0;
  digitalWrite(isiticiPWM, LOW);       // turn off TRIAC (and AC)
}                                 

// Turn on the TRIAC at the appropriate time
void dim_check() {                   
  if(zero_cross == true) {              
    if(i>=dim) {                     
      digitalWrite(isiticiPWM, HIGH); // turn on light       
      i=0;  // reset time step counter                         
      zero_cross = false; //reset zero cross detection
    } 
    else {
      i++; // increment time step counter                     
    }                                
  }                                  
} 
///////////////
void setup() {  

  pinMode(fanPWM,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(isiticiPWM, OUTPUT);


    attachInterrupt(0, zero_cross_detect, RISING);    // Attach an Interupt to----------------------------------->  Pin 2 (interupt 0) for Zero Cross Detection <<------------------------------------------------
    Timer1.initialize(freqStep);                      // Initialize TimerOne library for the freq we need
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(dim_check, freqStep);   


}



void loop()
{   
hiz=450;analogWrite(fanPWM,hiz);

for(int k=0;k<=255;k++)
{dim=k;
}                        


  }
```

Comment: `hiz=450;analogWrite(fanPWM,hiz);` -- PWM goes from 0 to 255. 450 is too high.

Comment: Your loop function doesn't make sense to me. You are ramping `dim` from 0 to 255 in full speed. I guess you want `dim` to be the currently set time to turn on the triac. Most likely `dim` will change so fast, that the Timer interrupt does not have time to actually apply the value. Somewhat a racing condition.

Comment: Zero crossing is used for AC to detect when the alternating current is as close to zero as possible so when a TRIAC/MOSFET doesn't generate a lot of transients!    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_cross_circuit